# CreateFile, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, Directory Management and Handles

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I am attempting to grab  a [directory handle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365258(v=vs.85).aspx) for the purpose of retrieving a an identifier for the directory. The documentation (linked above) specifies that the `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` flag needs to be passed to the `CreateFile` function in order to retrieve the handle, itself.

However, in consulting [pinvoke's](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.createfile) `kernel32.dll` signatures, most of the C# candidates look like the following:

```
    [DllImport("kernell32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
        string lpFileName,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAccess dwDesiredAccess,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileShare dwShareMode,
        IntPtr securityAttributes,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode dwCreationDisposition,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAttributes dwFlagsAndAttributes,
        IntPtr hTemplateFile
    );
```

The above one-to-one parameter mapping to the C++ [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) implies that the `dwFlagsAndAttributes` parameter is the placeholder for the `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS`; however, the `FileAttribute` enumeration doesn't appear to have a match for that flag.

Right now (and it's broken) my call looks like:

```
           var createdFolder =
                FileSystemInteractor.CreateFile(
                    fullPathWithFolderName,
                    FileAccess.Read,
                    FileShare.Read,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    FileMode.Open,
                    Kernel32.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
                    IntPtr.Zero
                );
```

`Kernel32` obviously contains the right flag. The compiler error received back is:

> cannot convert from 'uint' to 'System.IO.FileAttributes'

The error makes sense; I am just unsure of what massaging of the signature I am able to do because I am new to `extern` functions.

Is there a `FileAttributes` that corresponds to the needed flag? Do I need to change the `extern` signature?

Comment: Beyond applying a (FileAttributes)cast, the simple way is to declare the parameter as *uint* instead.

Comment: @HansPassant will that affect the ability for the extern signature to resolve to the dll?

Comment: No, this is a C function.  It is exported only by its name, the parameter types play no role.  Not even decorated by the calling convention, specific to winapi functions, it is just plain "CreateFile".

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, that seems to have done the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include this enum definition in your code:

```
[Flags]
private enum File_Attributes : uint
{
    Readonly = 0x00000001,
    Hidden = 0x00000002,
    System = 0x00000004,
    Directory = 0x00000010,
    Archive = 0x00000020,
    Device = 0x00000040,
    Normal = 0x00000080,
    Temporary = 0x00000100,
    SparseFile = 0x00000200,
    ReparsePoint = 0x00000400,
    Compressed = 0x00000800,
    Offline = 0x00001000,
    NotContentIndexed = 0x00002000,
    Encrypted = 0x00004000,
    Write_Through = 0x80000000,
    Overlapped = 0x40000000,
    NoBuffering = 0x20000000,
    RandomAccess = 0x10000000,
    SequentialScan = 0x08000000,
    DeleteOnClose = 0x04000000,
    BackupSemantics = 0x02000000,
    PosixSemantics = 0x01000000,
    OpenReparsePoint = 0x00200000,
    OpenNoRecall = 0x00100000,
    FirstPipeInstance = 0x00080000
}
```

The file attributes defined in System.IO does not include many attributes.